# Spring Boot Microservice Jackson JSON serialisation NON NULL

Tags: json, spring, serialization, jackson

I'm currently working on a Spring Boot ( Version 1.3.1 ) Microservice which connects to MongoDB backend and provides the backend data ( Ex: Provider object ) to the client via controller.

The project has got one class file which extends ResourceSupport ( Ex: ProviderResourceSupport ) and also another class which extends ResourceSupportAssembler class ( Ex: ProviderAssembler ) for generating Links to the Response objects.

Ideally my requirement is to customise the JSON objects on a need basis and as such using @JsonView ( followed this link - https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring ) and added Spring Jackson dependencies in the maven project.

I have also added spring.jackson.serialization-inclusion=non-null & spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true in the application.properties.

For one of the method in the controller, the response will be 'ResponseEntity< List< ProviderResourceSupport>>' , and this method is returning with a 'null' response if the data is not present.

I have added @JsonInclude(Include=NON_NULL) on my entity objects and controllers but still getting the 'null' response.

I don't want the 'null' as the response and request you to help me incase if anyone has faced the similar issue.

Comment: What should it return if the data is not present?

Comment: hi jny, it should return nothing but a HTTP status code of 404. I could able to check the data and if it is null i'm populating the status code to 404. The response status code is right populated with '404' but i should see no data. Instead i'm seeing a 'null' response.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this null properties escaping from json response extending a Jackson Mapper Bean but I don't use Spring Boot, take a quickly look and check if this is suitable for you

```
public class Jackson2ObjectMapperCustom extends Jackson2ObjectMapperFactoryBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        super.afterPropertiesSet();

        getObject().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL).setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);

        Hibernate5Module hibernateModule = new Hibernate5Module();
        hibernateModule.disable(Feature.USE_TRANSIENT_ANNOTATION);
        hibernateModule.enable(Feature.FORCE_LAZY_LOADING);
        getObject().registerModules(new JavaTimeModule(), hibernateModule);
        getObject().configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
        getObject().configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        getObject().setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"));
    }
}
```

And in my case I use Spring Xml configuration

```
<bean id="objectMapper" class="com.xxx.common.Jackson2ObjectMapperCustom" />

<mvc:annotation-driven>
    <mvc:message-converters>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter"/>
        <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">
            <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:message-converters>       
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Comment: Hi, Much appreciated and thanks for the same. But i'm using Spring Boot and Serialization Inclusion would be defined using application.properties files. So can't use this but thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hi all, Its now working as i have changed the response type from 'ResponseEntity< List< ProviderResourceSupport>>' to just 'ResponseEntity' and building the response object accordingly.